# Error in casting during creation of the Ontology class

Tags: java, agents-jade

I have created a vocabulary as `Network_Vocabulary` interface

I have created a class `CustomerAgentStatus` implements the `AgentAction`

I have then created an ontology class defining the ontology as:

I was getting an error as :

```
 java.lang.ExceptionInitializerError
```

I then followed instructions as had been suggested in a similar problem as follows:
http://jade.tilab.com/pipermail/jade-develop/2013q3/019284.html

Accordingly i put the

```
    **ontology =  NetworkOntology.getInstance();**
```

inside the setup() method and surrounded it with try/catch

After the stack Trace i got the following errors, I feel there is some error in the ontology class:

I'm getting an error as:

```
 Java.Lang.ClassCastException: jade.content.schema.Concept Schema cannot be cast to jade      .content.schema.PrimitiveSchema**
```

**My Ontology class implementation is as follows:**

```
package CellularNetwork;
import jade.content.onto.*;

import jade.content.schema.*;

public class Network_Ontology extends Ontology implements Network_Vocabulary {
public static final String ONTOLOGY_NAME = "Network-Ontology";
private static Ontology instance = new Network_Ontology();
public static Ontology getInstance() { return instance; }
// Private constructor

private Network_Ontology() {

  super(ONTOLOGY_NAME, BasicOntology.getInstance());

  try{

            AgentActionSchema cs = new AgentActionSchema(CUSTOMERAGENTSTATUS);

            add(cs, CustomerAgentStatus.class);

            cs.add(X_CO_ORDINATE, (PrimitiveSchema) getSchema(BasicOntology.FLOAT));

            cs.add(Y_CO_ORDINATE, (PrimitiveSchema) getSchema(BasicOntology.FLOAT));

            cs.add(DIRECTION, (PrimitiveSchema) getSchema(BasicOntology.STRING));

            cs.add(SPEED, (PrimitiveSchema) getSchema(BasicOntology.FLOAT));

            cs.add(CURRENT_PROVIDER,(PrimitiveSchema) getSchema(BasicOntology.AID));        

  }

  catch (OntologyException oe) {

  oe.printStackTrace();

  }

  }

 }// Network_Ontology
```

Comment: You should remove the Jade tag, it refers to the template engine, not what you're talking about. I couldn't remove it whitout editing at least 6 characters from your post...

Comment: Sorry, Sir. But I couldn't follow. Actually I was using Ontology feature in Jade for ACLMessaging. Where I came across this error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to represent an `AID` object with `CURRENT_PROVIDER`, then you have to add this schema as a `ConceptSchema` object, not as a `PrimitiveSchema` object. Just change this line:

```
cs.add(CURRENT_PROVIDER,(PrimitiveSchema) getSchema(BasicOntology.AID));
```

to this:

```
cs.add(CURRENT_PROVIDER,(ConceptSchema) getSchema(BasicOntology.AID));
```